# excel - get url from linked text

Tags: excel

I need to copy a column that has linked text and paste a column that shows all the URL’s for the linked text

Comment: Can you clarify please? Do you mean that you have a column with Hyperlinks (only hyperlinks? Or a mix of links and other contents?) and that you want to extract all the urls of these links? Do they have have to be on the same row as the original?

Answer (score 5):

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

In this case you can place it where you want. If you want, for example, the URL from a hyperlink in A1 to be listed in cell C25, then in cell C25 you would enter the following formula:

```
=GetURL(A1)
```

Comment: =GetURL(A1) function does not work in Excel 2013. At least not from my version of 2013

Comment: You can add the code inside a module, and try to use as above, it works too on excel 2013

Answer (score 2):

This [post](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/HyperlinkAddress.htm) discusses extracting the URL from a cell with a link in it using a custom formula.

Answer (score 0):

This immediately does the job, and add a separate url link column next to the column with the hyperlinked text:

https://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel

Extracting a URL from a hyperlink on Excel -- this worked for me!
If you want to run this operation one time
Open up a new workbook.

1. **Get into VBA (Press Alt+F11)**
2. **Insert a new module (Insert > Module)**
3. **Copy and Paste** the Excel user defined function below (customized function):

   Sub ExtractHL()

   Dim HL As Hyperlink

   For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks

   HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address

   Next

   End Sub
4. **Press F5 and click “Run”**
5. **Get out of VBA** (Press Alt+Q)
6. You will see a new column with a list of url added to the right.